# HTML formatting for SSRS textbox

Tags: html, reporting-services, textbox

SSRS texbox has an option to read HTML. The thing is I don't know how to edit HTML, so what I do is...

1. type up what I want with the formatting I need in a Word document
2. save the Word document as "Web Page, Filtered (*.htm;*.html)
3. open up the htm file in a text editor, copy paste the htm string and load that to my database table.
4. read the htm string from the database and display the rendered htm.

When I do this, I see that most of the formats I did in the Word document is there, but some of the formats are lost. For example, some of the paragraph indenting looks off.

How can I get the exact formatting I need without necessarily having to edit the hml string? Is there a way?

Comment: The short answer is - you can't.  Out of the box SSRS only supports a subset of HTML tags. I'm not sure what the limits are but I know from some work I did a few years ago that some tags are just ignored/not recognised.

Comment: The HTML that is supported is in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15